# What security problems could come from exposing phpinfo() to end users?

Tags: php, security

If a `phpinfo()` dump is shown to an end user, what is the worst that a malicious user could do with that information? What fields are most unsecure? That is, if your `phpinfo()` was publicly displayed, after taking it down, where should you watch/focus for malicious exploits?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Knowing the structure of your filesystem might allow hackers to execute directory traversal attacks if your site is vulnerable to them.

I think exposing phpinfo() on its own isn't necessarily a risk, but in combination with another vulnerability could lead to your site becoming compromised.

Obviously, the less specific info hackers have about your system, the better. Disabling phpinfo() won't make your site secure, but will make it slightly more difficult for them.

Answer (score 18):

Besides the obvious like being able to see if `register_globals` is On, and where files might be located in your include_path, there's all the `$_SERVER` (`$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]` can give clues to define a relative pathname to `/etc/passwd`) and `$_ENV` information (it's amazing what people store in `$_ENV`, such as encryption keys)

Comment: I'm curious.. Using PHPDotEnv I put all my passwords, API tokens and such in .env file, which is listed in .gitignore exactly for the purpose of safety. All does configuration is then available through `env('CONSTANT_NAME')` and `$_ENV['CONSTANT_NAME']` alike. Is this considered a security risk? If so, where do you store such data then?

Answer (score 8):

A well-configured, up-to-date system can afford to expose `phpinfo()` without risk.

Still, it is possible to get hold of so much detailed information - especially module versions, which could make a cracker's life easier when newly-discovered exploits come up - that I think it's good practice **not** to leave them up. Especially on shared hosting, where you have no influence on everyday server administration.

Comment: If it's (free) shared hosting, can't the attacker just create a website next to mine and investigate their own, and assume that mine is extremely similar to theirs?

Comment: @TWiStErRob sure, but that is going to be extremely rare - very few people are going to use a free hosting service for anything serious, and even then you won't know whether you'll end up on the same Server.

Comment: i believe this line of thought sane. if phpinfo leaks sensitive information there are probably more pressing security isssues with your hosting or hoster that should be addressed .

Answer (score 8):

The biggest problem is that many versions make XSS attacks simple by printing the contents of the URL and other data used to access it.

http://www.php-security.org/MOPB/MOPB-08-2007.html

Answer (score -7):

Hackers can use this information to find vulnerabilities and hack your site.

Comment: You could hardly have been more vague.

Comment: This is ever so vague. "Hack his site"? How? What sort of vulnerabilities? Can you give some examples of vulnerabilities that might be revealed in this way?

Comment: Just Google 'phpinfo hack'. Version info and installed modules constitute information a hacker can use to attack specific vulnerabilities in old and unpatched versions.

Answer (score -7):

Honestly, not much. Personally, I frequently leave `phpinfo()` pages up.

If you have some serious misconfigurations (e.g. PHP is running as root), or you're using old and vulnerable versions of some extensions or PHP itself, this information will be more exposed. On the other hand, you also wouldn't be protected by not exposing `phpinfo()`; you should have instead take care of having your server up-to-date and correctly configured.

Comment: Perhaps post a link where phpinfo() can be seen in one of your sites, and let's experiment whether it stands the test of time. I sure don't know how to exploit it, but perhaps we will all learn from it one way or the other. If you're not absolutely sure about your doing, then it's best **not to do so** though!