# Is it safe to publicly display phpinfo()?

Tags: php, security

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What security problems could come from exposing phpinfo() to end users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196011/what-security-problems-could-come-from-exposing-phpinfo-to-end-users)

Is it safe to publicly display the results of

```
<? PHP phpinfo() ?>
```

Or would that make it easier for my site to get hacked?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196011/what-security-problems-could-come-from-exposing-phpinfo-to-end-users

Comment: Why downvote?  It's a legit question even if it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

As with any security question its a tradeoff.

Yes, it may make your site easier to get hacked, but that might be 'worth it' if you have a pressing need to make such info available.

YMMV.