# my php script enters blank info into mysql db!

Tags: php, mysql, forms

When I try to enter data from a form I have made it adds a new entry as i can see from phpmyadmin but does not transfer other details across

I am using a simple form that collects 9 fileds post is to update.php. Here is what I have in update.php

```
<?php
$realname = $_POST['realname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$gamename = $_POST['gamename'];
$gamelevel = $_POST['gamelevel'];
$itemlevel = $_POST['itemlevel'];
$class = $_POST['class'];
$played = $_POST['played'];
$support = $_POST['support'];

mysql_connect ("localhost", "mydb_userid", "MYPASSWORD") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("mydb_recruitment");

$query="INSERT INTO applicants (ID, realname, age, country, gamename, gamelevel, itemlevel, class, played, support)VALUES ('NULL','".$realname."','".$age."','".$country."','".$gamename."','".$gamelevel."','".$itemlevel."','".$class."','".$played."','".$support."')";

mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating DB');

echo "You have sucessfully sent an application. Your details will be reviewed and someone will get back to you";

?>
```

Hope someone can help, searching the net seems to sugest something about global variables - but i dont know if i have control of that as its an hosted site.

this is the signup form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Candidate Registration</title>
</head>

<body>

<form medthod="post" action="update.php">

Real Name:<br />
<input type="text" name="realname" size="50" /><br />

Age:<br />
<input type="text" name="age" size="10" /><br />

Country:<br />
<input type="text" name="country" size="20" /><br />

In Game Name:<br />
<input type="text" name="gamename" size="30" /><br />

In Game Level:<br />
<input type="text" name="gamelevel" size="10" /><br />

In Game Item Level:<br />
<input type="text" name="itemlevel" size="10" /><br />

Class Played:<br />
<input type="text" name="class" size="30" /><br />

How long have you played wow?:<br />
<input type="text" name="played" size="10" /><br />

Please enter a brief statement of why you want to join:<br />
<input type="text" name="support" size="5000" /><br />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="Update DB" />

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the update.php form

```
<?php
$realname = $_POST['realname'];
$age = $_POST['age'];
$country = $_POST['country'];
$gamename = $_POST['gamename'];
$gamelevel = $_POST['gamelevel'];
$itemlevel = $_POST['itemlevel'];
$class = $_POST['class'];
$played = $_POST['played'];
$support = $_POST['support'];

mysql_connect ("localhost", "mydb_daniel", "mypwd") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("mydb_recruitment");

$query="INSERT INTO applicants (ID, realname, age, country, gamename, gamelevel, itemlevel, class, played, support)VALUES ('NULL','".$realname."','".$age."','".$country."','".$gamename."','".$gamelevel."','".$itemlevel."','".$class."','".$played."','".$support."')";

mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating DB');

echo "You have sucessfully sent an application. Your details will be reviewed and someone will get back to you";

?>
```

I understand peoples concerns about sercurity, but please understand this only for me to mess around with and produce a basic signup form for my guild, i wont be requesting credit card details :)

Comment: Have you specified the name attributes of the html form elements, e.g. `<input type="text" name="realname" />`

Comment: you spelt method wrong, please update and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your form method set to POST? - unless you have explicitly added this the variables will be within the `$_GET` superglobal so your variables would be like this:

```
$realname = $_GET['realname'];
```

If it is set to POST - please do a `var_dump($_POST)` at the top of your script and see if any variables are making it to your script.

Something else that i've seen before is caused when people are redirecting in a `.htaccess` from domain.com to www.domain.com and they post a script explicity to domain.com/script.php and the script then redirects to www.domain.com/script.php and this empties the POST.

**EDIT**

You have spelt `method` wrong in your form tag - if you update this then it should work as your misspelling will be causing the variables to be sent as GET vars.

You can fix your security issues in a basic way like this:

```
$realname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['realname']);
$age = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['age']);
$country = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['country']);
$gamename = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gamename']);
$gamelevel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['gamelevel']);
$itemlevel = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['itemlevel']);
$class = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['class']);
$played = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['played']);
$support = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['support']);
```

Comment: Christ, way to hog points. Edit your answer to include the answer, edit to include my suggestion, actually ASK the asker to select your answer. Really? Where's your integrity man? Note, I asked in the comments to mine after you out of absolute frustration.

Comment: @Zenph haha. I edited my answer to include the answer to the question that *i* answered. I added the mysql_real_escape_string to answer his further question about security, i wasn't aware you invented this technique! I'm not trying to hog points at all but its frustrating when new posters dont understand that they need to accept an answer. I would have been happy for you to have the accepted answer had you actually answered the question he asked which - if you rememeber - was not actually about security but about why his form wasnt working

Comment: @Daniel move your `mysql_connect` and `mysql_select_db` to the top of your script after the opening php tag

Comment: I'm not even bothered about whose answer was selected. I actually up-voted your answer after it was selected because the security info was in there. I just feel a bit 'dirty' after your complete lack of attention to security turned into an edited answer about it.

Comment: @Zenph Dude, come on. complete lack of attention to security is taking it a bit far. I'll drop you an upvote as i agree with much of what you've said, now move on.

Answer (score 1):

Whoa, slow down. You've not even escaped this data!

```
$realname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['realname']);
```

Or to escape it all:

```
$_POST = array_map('mysql_real_escape_string', $_POST);
```

Note the second solution isn't entirely reliable. Can produce some strange results. It is generally better to run these inputs through a function/class for validation and cleansing.

On your ghost issue, try this and note response after form submit (put right at top):

```
var_dump($_POST);
exit;
```

You spelled method attribute wrong in your query, that is why it isn't working.

Comment: true, but one thing at a time :)

Comment: Not at all, should be done at the same time! This kind of thing should be required. Developers are only going to shift their thinking when people they listen to (like you) keep repeating to them: security first!

Comment: i agree with you - the array_map suggestion is not a good start though as it really neglects fundamentals and should only be considered when you're in a position to understand the positive *and* negative issues it will cause.

Comment: array(0) { } You have sucessfully sent an application. Your details will be reviewed and someone will get back to you

Comment: @Daniel - are you doing any redirection in a `.htaccess` like i mentioned in my post?

Comment: i also tried to change the syntax to all: $_POST['realname'] etc etc but this returned a T_variable syntax issue.

Comment: @Daniel: that's the problem. No data is being posted. Take note of seengee's edit below about checking whether there is a redirect prior to this script. The action="" attribute of your form should go directly to this script.

Comment: @Daniel - just in case try switching the `var_dump($_POST)` to `var_dump($_REQUEST)` and see if its still empty

Comment: i'm not doing any redirection that i'm aware of, i've simpley created a db under phpmyadmin, added some tables. Created 1 php file for the form with post, and created another php file to do what i've pasted, but this just puts ghost entries in.

Comment: @Daniel - please try what i've mentioned. also, if you can post a public URL please do that and just add `<?php phpinfo();?>` to it

Comment: using var_dump($_REQUEST) gives : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /home/avguildc/public_html/update.php  on line 3

Comment: @Daniel - did you put a semi-colon after - should be: `<?php var_dump($_REQUEST);`

Comment: Are you serious seengee? You're asking somebody to post a phpinfo file to stackoverflow? I understand you're trying to help but you really don't focus on security much, do you? @Daniel, you have to add ; to the end of every line. var_dump($_REQUEST);

Comment: @Daniel - your phpinfo looks fine. please post the full content of both files to your original posting

Comment: @Zenph - i think you wil find there actually is very little direct danger in showing the contents of a phpinfo file. either way i was going to ask him to remove it after he posted it anyway.

Comment: @Zenph - a recent discussion of it here actually  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196011/what-security-problems-could-come-from-exposing-phpinfo-to-end-users

Comment: @seengee, I know that but it's obvious he has no idea what he's doing (missing semi-colon). Don't want him thinking it is common practice to share this kind of info on a public forum. I know you mean well, sorry. I'm one of the 'unlucky' ones who was bitten. Security is top priority.

Comment: @daniel - you spelt method wrong, please make sure this isnt spelt wrong in your original file as this will mean your variables are being sent as GET vars

Comment: its all working, do I have to be concerned about sercurity using this method??

Comment: @Daniel no worries. please click to accept my answer to your question so other people can see the resolution :)

Comment: @Daniel if you add `mysql_real_escape_string()` round each $_POST variable this will solve your security issues in a basic way

Comment: @Daniel, YES you do have to be worried about security. Please read: sql injection. Your code is currently wide open. Doesn't matter whose answer you accept.

Comment: how will mysql_real_escape_string() secure me from sql injection?

Comment: @Daniel i would follow Zenph's suggestion, you need to read about some php security fundamentals

Comment: @Daniel, it escapes your data. You should read up on it. It's an important topic and can be easily prevented by using mysql_real_escape_string(). You only have to use that on values you use in sql queries. I've edited my answer to. I feel if you accept as correct answer will be at the top with security concerns which people SHOULD be reading. Thanks.

Comment: i've updated with the security suggestions but now recieve: Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: Access denied for user 'nobody'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/avguildc/public_html/update.php  on line 2

Warning: mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /home/avguildc/public_html/update.php on line 2

Comment: @Daniel, you need to connect to the db before using `mysql_real_escape_string` - more your `mysql_connect` line to before your other variable assignments

Comment: @tobyodavies - okay that worked :) time to buy a few books on php me thinks :)

Comment: And don't forget the PHP manual at php.net - the function reference is usually really good. (one of the best features of PHP if you ask me - the documentation)